# Combine AWS S3 bucket policies to include both Allow and Deny rules

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have two policies and would like to merge into one single bucket policy.

Is it possible to merge deny and allow policies into one single policy?
In this example does the policy allow IP ranges other than 54.240.143.0/24?

The policy should only allow access from the VPC endpoint and IP range 54.240.143.0/24

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "IPAllow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
      "Condition": {
         "IpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": "54.240.143.0/24"}
      } 
    } 
  ]
}


{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Id": "Policy1415115909152",
   "Statement": [
     {
       "Sid": "Access-to-specific-VPCE-only",
       "Action": "s3:*",
       "Effect": "Deny",
       "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket",
                    "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"],
       "Condition": {
         "StringNotEquals": {
           "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-1a2b3c4d"
         }
       },
       "Principal": "*"
     }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please state your rules requirements in English? It is currently saying "Only access this bucket via this VPC-Endpoint" AND "Only if it is coming from this Public IP address", which appears to be contradictory.

Comment: It's also usually best to remember that access is denied by default, so you can usually write what you need as "allow if" instead of "deny unless," which makes things simpler in some cases since *any* matching deny rule will always win over any matching allow.

Comment: The policy should only allow access from the VPC endpoint and IP range 54.240.143.0/24

Comment: There's an exception to the "access is denied by default" rule cited in the comment above, and that is with IP addresses. Adding a rule granting an IP address access to a bucket has no effect; the bucket remains open to all IP addresses. You have to have a DENY rule in order to restrict IP addresses. See [this post](https://pete.wtf/2012/05/01/how-to-setup-aws-s3-access-from-specific-ips/) for an example, and note that the [AWS example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-3) is dangerously wrong: the bucket remains open.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you reverse your second policy and add the condition to the first? You are currently denying access from everywhere except one vpc. So, instead, add a condition that allows access to this vpc in the first policy.

Comment: I think it's premature to give any advice on this question, until the clarification from the comments is provided.  You never access a bucket over a VPC endpoint with a public IPv4 source address -- in fact, when traversing a VPC endpoint, your source address is meaningless and cannot be used for access control, so it is not clear what OP means by "other than."